# Borel sets preserved under open maps?

Tags: measure-theory, integration, gn.general-topology

Given open map f: $R^n$ to $R^n$ such that each open set $U\in R^n$, $f(U)$ is also open. Are Borel sets in $R^n$ preserved under f?

Motivation: Pre-image of Borel sets under continuous map is a Borel set in $R^n$.

The problem of the analogous statement above is when $U$ and $V$ are open, $f(U\cap V) \subset f(U)\cap f(V)$, but they may not be equal. Is it possible to construct a concrete counter-example to the statement?

Comment: You need injectivity for the mapping f.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every [analytic set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set) ($\Sigma^1_1$ set) of reals is the projection of a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, and the projection map $p(x,y)\mapsto x$ is an open map. So the standard examples of non-Borel $\Sigma^1_1$ sets are also examples where Borel sets are not preserved by an open map $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$.

But you asked for an open map $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, with the same domain and codomain, and the reasoning above concerned only an open map $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. Here is one way to fix the issue and make an open map $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ having the image of a Borel set being non-Borel. Let $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be any function whose restriction to every open interval is onto. One can make such a function by using Cantor's interleaving digits trick, combined with the idea of [Conway's base 13 function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function). This function is an open map, since every nonempty open set maps onto the whole space. Now, define $f(x,y,z)=(x,z_0,z_1)$, where $h(z)=(z_0,z_1)$. It is easy to see that the function $f$ is an open map. Meanwhile, every analytic set $A$ has the form $x\in A\iff \exists y B(x,y)$, where $B\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is a Borel set. Let $C=B\times\mathbb{R}$, which is Borel. Consider the image set $f[C]$, and note that $(x,0,0)\in f[C]$ if and only if there is some $y$ such that $(x,y)\in B$, since in this case we will find a $z$ with $h(z)=(0,0)$; hence, $(x,0,0)\in f[C]$ if and only if $x\in A$, and so the intersection of $f[C]$ with the $x$-axis is $A$, a non-Borel set. So $f[C]$ cannot be Borel if $A$ is not. So this is a case where we have an open map $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ taking a Borel set to a non-Borel set.

Comment: But I admit, this doesn't quite get a counterexample with an open map $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ as requested...

Comment: If one uses Baire space or Cantor space, which are homeomorphic to their squares, rather than $\mathbb{R}$, then one can easily fold in another dimension to transfer this example to have the same domain and codomain. 

Comment: I have realized how to do it with $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ itself, and edited the answer.

Comment: Here's a cheap trick that gives an open $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.  Let $E$ be Vitali equivalence on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $g \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be any Borel function sending distinct points to $E$-unrelated points.  Then define $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = y$ if $\exists z\ (x \mathrel{E} g(y,z))$, and say $f(x) = 0$ if no such $(y,z)$ exists.  This function is open (since the image of any open set is $\mathbb{R}$ by density of $E$-classes). [cont.]

Comment: Now if $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is any Borel set with non-Borel projection, then $g[B]$ is again Borel (as $g$ is injective), but $f[g[B]]$ is the projection of $B$, which was non-Borel.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Projection from $\mathbb R^2$ onto $\mathbb R$ is open, but the image of a $G_\delta$ set can be any analytic set.  So there are non-Borels among them.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set

**edit**  Not a counterexample from a space to itself as required.

So a counterexample has to be an open map $\mathbb R^n$ to itself, but *not* at-most-countable-to-one, since those maps do preserve Borel, as I recall.

Comment: The open map was to be from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself. See Joel's second comment below his answer. 